# Multiple Alarms In Android Using Android Services

Tags: android

This is my save button in which i put alarm. But problem is if i add 1 alarm it works great but if i add an alarm next minute before last alarm has triggered it cancels last alarm and updates to new one, i tried changing request code but it isnt working for me

```
        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_rem);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                title_txt = title.getText().toString();
                description_txt = description.getText().toString();
                id++;


                addRemInDb a = new addRemInDb();
                int v = a.insert(title_txt, hour, minute, mMonth, mDay, mYear, description_txt);
                //a.deleteTable();
                a.closeDB();
                if(v == -1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Title & Time Must Not Be Same",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {                                               
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                    //Setting alarm to be triggered on specified date and time
                    cal.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay, hour, minute, seconds);

                    requestcode++; // Here request code is adding every time when i click in save button

                    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

                    alarmIntent.putExtra("title", title_txt);           //This is title for notification
                    alarmIntent.putExtra("note", description_txt);      //This is Description for notification
                    alarmIntent.putExtra("rq", requestcode);

                    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), requestcode, alarmIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);



                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);                       

                    finish();


                }       

            }
        });
```

This is my AlarmReciever class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends Service
{
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) 
{
    super.onStart(intent, startId);     


    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    String title=extras.getString("title");
    String note=extras.getString("note");
    int requestcode = extras.getInt("rq");


    NotificationManager nManger = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notify, "Reminder", System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), requestcode, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), note, title, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    nManger.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Requestcode im generating was not working as i added this line 
and used intent_id as my request code it worked perfectly fine

final int intent_id= (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: if you are creating alarm via pending intents and alarm manager then you can delete alarm 1 by 1. For that you have to again create pending intent similar to which you created while setting alarm. And then with alarmmanager.cancel() function you can delete alarm. Keep in mind that your request code in pending intent should be same which you put while setting alarm.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` on your `PendingIntent`.